# Advantages and Disadvantages of Axis2 over WCF

Tags: wcf, apache-axis, basichttpbinding

We have a WCF Service in our application suits that is being used to synchronize data among the different devices of a same user.

We are facing some trouble with WCF as it leaves high memory footprints on the server and also the degree of concurrency is significantly low. we are using Basic Http Binding.

So, i have started working of Axis2 to check if this can help us in this. So before I start I would like to know Advantages/Disadvantages of Axis2 over WCF so if any of you can share a comprehensive article specially keeping performance in mind.

One biggest Advantage we are seeking is that it is open source and free to use in sense of hosting environment as we can deploy it on Linux platform as well.

Comment: WCF is "free to use" once you've got the Windows license (which you'd have if you were hosting on windows...)

Comment: :) you know what is the cost of Windows Server 2008 :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Axis2, although we once decided to use it but rejected it in favor of WCF. One of the primary reasons for doing so was that there isn't a large community of people using Axis2 who can help you out if you are stuck somewhere. Additionally, there are, I think, only a couple of books on the topic.

We were looking at the Axis2/C, the C version of the framework. I guess the Java version would be a bit easier to use. You should also check out an earlier question regarding Axis2 [WCF Interop with Axis2 using WS-Trust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785652/wcf-interop-with-axis2-using-ws-trust)